# Specify box with header around listing

Tags: listings, minted

I am using the `minted` package to insert code listings for different programming languages in my document. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}
\newminted{python}{autogobble, bgcolor=bg}
%... other minted environments for other languages

\begin{document}

\begin{listing}[htb]
  \begin{pythoncode}
    def myClass:
      pass
  \end{pythoncode}
  \caption{Some Python}
  \label{lst:python}
\end{listing}

\end{document}
```

Now, what I would like to do is specify for each listing what programming language is being used in in. I was thinking about putting a box around the listing, with a header in which I can specify the language. I would like this language label to be on the right end of the header.

Are there any packages that can help with this? How could I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation of `minted` says for `bgcolor` key:

> Background color of the listing. Be aware that this option has several
>   limitations (described below); see “Framing alternatives” below for
>   more powerful alternatives.

In section "Framing alternatives", you have:

> If you want more reliable and advanced options for background colors
>   and framing, you should consider a more advanced framing package such
>   as `mdframed` or `tcolorbox`.

Below you'll find two boxes with `tcolorbox` and standard `minted` (more accurate: `fancyvrb`) possibilities: You see the limitations of standard solution where background color box is larger than the frame.  Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}

\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}
\newminted{python}{%
  autogobble                               ,
  bgcolor       = bg                       ,
  frame         = single                   ,
  framerule     = 1mm                      ,
  framesep      = 3mm                      ,
  label         = \textrm{\textbf{python}} ,
  labelposition = topline
}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{minted}

\newtcblisting{tcbpythoncode}[1][python]{%
  colback         = yellow!5        ,
  colframe        = yellow!50!black ,
  listing only                      ,
  title           = #1              ,
  halign title    = right           ,
  fonttitle       = \bfseries       ,
  listing engine  = minted          ,
  minted language = python
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcbpythoncode}
def myClass:
  pass
\end{tcbpythoncode}

\begin{listing}
\begin{pythoncode}
def myClass:
  pass
\end{pythoncode}
\end{listing}

\end{document}
```

> [image]